# How to print odd character from string using powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

I am trying to print odd character from string `Consequences` using powershell.

below code is working , but is there any other easy way to perform this task? like using `-split` function?

```
$student_name = "Consequences"
$out = ""
for($i = 0; $i -lt $student_name.Length ;$i++ ){
    if ($i % 2 -eq 0 ){
        $out += $student_name[$i]
    }
}
$out
```

it should print output as below

```
Cneune
```

Comment: @EBGreen Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I always forget about that. Retracting the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do with a single `foreach` loop and `string` methods:

```
$word = 'Consequences'
@(foreach ($c in ($word -split '')) {
    if ($word.IndexOf($c) % 2 -eq 0) { $c }
}) -join ''
```

I use an array operator (`@()`) to force the `foreach` to return items as a single collection so the `-join` works.

Answer (score 2):

And two more to demonstrate the various techniques available. The first one uses the unary form of `-join`, takes advantage of the fact that statements can return values and counts by 2 instead of checking to see if the number is even.

```
$student_name = "Consequences"
-join @(for ($i = 0; $i -lt $student_name.Length; $i += 2) {
        $student_name[$i]
})
```

The second solution is similar to the first, but uses the `foreach` loop and the `$foreach` enumerator instead of a `for` loop.

```
-join $(foreach ($c in [char[]] $student_name) {
        $c
        [void] $foreach.MoveNext()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Fine, I'll do a proper answer:

```
$out = (0..$student_name.length | ?{($_ % 2) -eq 0} | %{$student_name[$_]}) -join ''
```

This gets all the integers from 0 to the number of characters in the word (`0..$student_name.length`). Then it filters to only keep the odd integers (`?{($_ % 2) -eq 0}`). It uses those integers to get each character from the string at that position in the string (`%{$student_name[$_]}`). Lastly it takes the characters and joins them back together into a single string (`-join ''`).

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution based on .NET Linq in Powershell, propably the fastest solution: Check if first bit of indexer is set to determine odd character. Remove Zero-Characters from char-array and join to string.

```
$out = 'Consequences'
([Linq.Enumerable]::Select($out, [Func[char, int, char]] { param( $c, $i ) if( -not ($i -band 1) ) { $c } }) | ? {$_ -ne 0 }) -join ''
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my Friend suggested this answer, although its same concept.

```
$long_word = "Consequences"
-join ($long_word -split '(.{2})').ForEach({$_[0..0]})
```

Comment: `-split '(.{2})' this will split given string at every 2nd character.`
we can split string for any number.
Example split string with 3 char.
`$string -split "(.{3})" -ne ""`
# Output
'abc' 'def'